# My 2003 Silverado air bag light is on

Tags: chevrolet, silverado, supplemental-restraint-system

2003 Chevy Silverado air bag dash light on, but get no code when scanned. What might be the issue?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 you should put this as an answer : I agree it may or may not be the op’s problem, but it may well help others so should not be « lost » as a comment.

Comment: @SolarMike - Took your advice. TY.

Answer (score 1):

Realize you need a code reader which can read your SRS system. The codes come from a different part of the system on the CAN Bus. Your local AutoZone or what have you will not have the ability to read the codes.

I had my airbag light come on in my '06 Silverado. It was [the impact sensor](https://www.rockauto.com/en/catalog/chevrolet,2006,silverado+1500,5.3l+v8,1432418,body,impact+sensor,1564) located at the bottom of the radiator core support. There are two of them. My son's '05 Silverado had the same issue. This is a very common malady for our trucks.

If this is indeed the issue, changing them out is really easy. There is one bolt and one connector (for each sensor). You can access them directly from the bottom by crawling under the truck and looking directly up at the core support. They will be located about at the ends of where the radiator itself is at. You'd want to follow all precautionary procedures, by draining the power of the air bag system. If you don't, you can possibly deploy the air bags while you're doing the work. If you disconnect the battery, then press the brake pedal for 15 seconds, it should completely deplete the system and you'd be safe to proceed. It takes approximately 5 minutes per side to remove/replace the sensors.

Answer (score 0):

I just made a video about this very problem

I have a 2012 Chevy Volt and while most of my mechanical experience is with normal gas engines, the Volt intrigued me enough to buy one.

I had the check airbag light come on and was able to resolve it super simply - check it out on YouTube: https://youtu.be/0bfAr-scIcE

Comment: Hi Build Brothers, welcome to the site. We ask that you don't post link-only answers, as they can go stale (e.g. if you were to later remove your video) - could you summarise the technique demonstrated in the youtube video?